# search from database table is not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
$va=($_GET['search']);
$search=$bd->execute("search","*","page_description LIKE '%$va%' or page_title LIKE '%$va%' limit 8 ");
```

$search is my query i.e **select * from search where page_description LIKE '%$va%' or page_title LIKE '%$va%' limit 8**

If the user search for domino's , it is going to save it in $va . but after that I am having a problem in my query , its shows me the error sometimes

**fatal man: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's%' or page_title LIKE '%dunkin's%' limit 8' at line 1 
Query Run :SELECT * FROM search WHERE page_description LIKE '%dunkin's%' or page_title LIKE '%dunkin's%' limit 8**

but when i use this 
$va=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
Its shows me null result but i have dinkin' donuts in my table search 
So any one can tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

**Try that**

```
$search=$bd->execute("search","*","page_description LIKE \'%$va%\' or page_title LIKE \'%$va%\' limit 8 ");
```

**OR**

```
$search=$bd->execute("search","*","page_description LIKE %'" + $va + "'% or page_title LIKE %'" + $va + "'% limit 8 ");
```